# reactor-core crash and restart state

Tags: project-reactor, camunda, reactor, reactive-streams

I am new to reactor-core, have done Erlang in the past.

Hopefully a quick question.

Say we send out a message 'A' and then expect a response in x minutes. If the response does not come in x minutes, we run a fallback routine.

It can be done using Flux or Mono with method timeout(duration, fallback)

[Here is the API from the rector-core site](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#timeout-java.time.Duration-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-)

```
public final Mono<T> timeout(Duration timeout,
                             Mono<? extends T> fallback)
Switch to a fallback Mono in case no item arrives within the given Duration.
If the fallback Mono is null, signal a TimeoutException instead.
Parameters:
timeout - the timeout before the onNext signal from this Mono
fallback - the fallback Mono to subscribe to when a timeout occurs
Returns:
a Mono that will fallback to a different Mono in case of timeout
```

What happens if the JVM crashes and restarts ?

Let's say that the crash and restart takes y minutes.(assume y is less than x)

Does reactor-core know that a crash happened ? 
Can it restart the processing of the flow, knowing it now needs to wait for (x-y) minutes now ?

I do know that Camunda stores state in a RDBMS. Hence maybe it should recover from a crash.

Comment: How is camunda relevant to your reactor question.

Comment: @JanGalinski Camunda looks like a framework, which can do flow based timeouts, and can store status and data in an RDBMS, and hence must be able to recover from failures.

Comment: Camunda is a process engine ... so you model a process that represents your planned actions and run it. "inside" its a classic relational/transactional data model that keeps states. Persisting the state allows to restart and continue ... but what is the use case? How comes you try to decide between reactive stream processing and a relational process engine?

Comment: @JanGalinski Thanks for the answer, i understand i, am looking at diverse things. My use case is to consume an individual message from a senders, send the same individual message out to one receiver. The receiver is expected to send a response after some time(in minutes). If there is no response there is an alternate flow to be triggered. Now do know this could be 25000 to 50000 messages per second, and also if any processing node goes down, then processing must start from where ever it stopped, especially for timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactor is a library aiming at processing live event within the boundaries of a JVM, both in terms of locality of the data being processed AND the lifecycle. Persisting state (to the disk or anywhere really) or recovering from JVM crashes are beyond the scope of the library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Makes sense.